# Move selected menu list item to first list position

Tags: jquery

I have a top menu with three unordered list items. The list item thats clicked shall move to the left, into first position. I tried some things with prepend() like below but I am not getting it to work. Thanks for any hint.

html:

```
<div class='subpage_top_nav'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><center>Gabione</center></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><center>Bewerte Erde</center></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><center>Natursteinsatz</center></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.subpage_top_nav li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().append(this);

});
```

Comment: Your code, with `prepend()` instead, works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dyeJ7/

Comment: Also for me, what browser did you used ?

Comment: yeh I had some issues :) its working for me too now. Muchos Grazias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) is working fine.

```
$('.subpage_top_nav li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LQNsr/)**</kbd>

Comment: can i steal the demo fiddle button ?!

Comment: still .. im stealing it

Answer (score 3):

Use [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

```
$('.subpage_top_nav li').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/29cBw/

Comment: What's different than picbig wrote ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes - `append` vs. `prepend`.

Comment: Good, I don't have snake eyes anymore :)